# Diameter of a circle with 3 coordinates

Tags: geometry, circles

The question is: A circle has the points $A=(6,-1)$ $B=(10,-3)$ and $C=(-2,-9)$ on its circumference. A diameter of the circle is drawn which is parallel to BC. How far apart are the two parallel lines?

I managed to get the center of the circle $(5,-8)$, however I am now stuck.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: What is the geometric definition of a circle?  (What is special about all the points on the circle?)

Comment: Or if you draw a normal from the center of the circle to BC, where do you think it will hit BC? (Hint: Almost no calculation needed. Draw a picture.)

Answer (score 0):

that is a pretty good start.

Hint:

the line through $BC$ must hit the circle at $BC$. the distance between the mid-point of BC and the centre must be the same as the shortest distance from the BC and its parallel diameter
 (draw a picture  and convince yourself, and why is this true?)

work out the midpoint and calculate the distance to the centre.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I got it now:)

Comment: @Laila no worries

Answer (score 0):

If center of circle is $O(5,-8)$ You need to find the straight line $n$ that  is perpendicular to line $BC$ wich passes to $O$ then you find the point $N=n\cap BC$ finally you look for distance $ON$